# DAX found a error with my formula

Tags: ssas, dax, tabular

Using AdventureWorks 2014 I'm doing a simple TOTALYTD formula.  Everything looks correct but every time I hit enter I get Tabular Model Designer error "We found a problem with this formula.  Try clicking Insert Function on the Formulas tab to fix it, or click Help for more info on common formula problems."  I see no indication of what the error is so I can't even troubleshoot it.  I'm new to DAX and just following along in a tutorial (Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Business Intelligence Development by PACKT Publishing)
I've tried these and nothing works.
    =TOTALYTD(SUM(InternetSales[SalesAmount]),Date[DateKey])
    =TOTALYTD(SUM(InternetSales[SalesAmount]),Date[FullDateAlternateKey])
    =TOTALYTD(SUM(InternetSales[SalesAmount]),'Date'[FullDateAlternateKey])
    =TOTALYTD(SUM(InternetSales[SalesAmount]),DateTime[FullDateAlternateKey])

Comment: Are you in a locale that uses semi-colon instead of comma for the argument separator?

Comment: No commas work in everything else.  If I change the comma to  semicolon, it tells me "The syntax for ';' is incorrect.

Comment: I just tried the same formula directly from the server and I was able to get it to accept the formula.  So it lets me on the server but not on my local PC.  Anyone know why that would be?  I tried opening the tabular file that is on the server where I had added the formula and saved.  the tabular file opens but the formula is gone.  I should be able to work locally and not have to log in to the server.

Comment: Does CALCULATE( SUM( InternetSales[SalesAmount] ), DATESYTD( 'Date'[DateKey] ) ) work? TOTALYTD() is just syntactic sugar for that construction.

Comment: No, it doesn't work either.  Same error.

Comment: Can you define *any* measures locally?

Comment: Sounds like your sandbox model behind your VS project is messed up. Defintely clean and rebuild your VS project. Also perhaps remove and recreate your workspace database and/or point your workspace DB to a new model instance?